# ABCpdf AddImageHtml two html in one page

Tags: abcpdf

Is it possible to add two html string in one page ?

When the pdf is rendered, I can only see the second html. It seems that the first one is overwritten

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have found that you can do this is to add each HTML to its own document then merge both documents together

```
theDoc.AddImageUrl(Url1);
theDoc2.AddImageUrl(Url2);

theDoc.Append(theDoc2);
```

Comment: Hmm... ok. let me try it first. But I'm wondering what will happen if the remaining space in that page is not enough to populate all data from 2nd html

Comment: This will create two separate pdf documents then add them together, so they are chained. the only other way would be to add the HTML from the two pages together before adding it to the pdf engine.